# Windows Phone 8.1 RT app back navigation issue after using DataTranferManager

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, back-button

In my app (WP 8.1 RT) I use the DataTransferManager to share content. After launching the sharing UI, the app returns back to the page(2nd page of the app). And then, when I press the back button it's suppose to go back to the previous page(MainPage) but instead, its exiting the app. Back buttonn is working properly before launching the sharing UI. And this doesn't happen when debugging.

This is the order of the events happening.

Page1(main) -> Page2 -> (Calling DataTransferManager)SharingUI -> Backto Page2. Then back button exits the app.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue. How do you handler back button pressing? Try using NavigationHelper instead of using custom BackPressed handler. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes i use NavigaionHelper. Misusing the BackPressed event caused the issue. It's solved now. :)